# Can I use Globe Temperature in CBE Thermal Comfort Tool?

Tags: simulation

I have a question regarding the CBE comfort tool and the input for operative temperature . I have measured data for globe temperature in a room . Can I use that data as the operative temperature value in the CBE tool ? My understanding is that both metrics are similar but I am not sure they are interchangeable . Is that technically appropriate ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support issue, specific to a tool; it's not a programming question and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

[Operative temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operative_temperature) and [globe temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_radiant_temperature) are two different parameters and cannot be used interchangeably. The globe temperature is a measured variable that is used to estimate the mean radiant temperature. The mean radiant temperature and the air temperature can then be combined to calculate the operative temperature. The equations to derive the operative temperature are quite simple, however, to further simplify the calculation of the mean radiant temperature, we have included the Globe Temperature tool in the CBE thermal comfort tool.

Please follow these steps to calculate the mean radiant temperature:

1. In the ASHRAE-55 page please select the `psychrometric (air-temperature)` chart from the drop-down menu above the chart.
2. Click on `Globe temp` and enter all the required variables. If you did not measure air velocity and the air in the space was still you may assume that the air speed was equal to 0.1 m/s or less.
3. Click on set mean radiant temperature.

You can now calculate the operative temperature for occupants engaged in near sedentary physical activity (with metabolic rates between 1.0 met and 1.3 met), not in direct sunlight, and not exposed to air velocities greater than 0.10 m/s (20 fpm) with the simplified equation provided in the [Operative temperature - Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operative_temperature)